# With an iPhone 13 pro, is it possible to record video and lidar simultaneously?

Tags: video, camera

What I would like to have is a 4K 30fps video synchronized with a low-res lidar depth stream.

Is it possible to record this with an iPhone 13 pro? If it can't be done natively, is there an app that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example [Enhancing Live Video by Leveraging TrueDepth Camera Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/enhancing_live_video_by_leveraging_truedepth_camera_data). LIDAR and the camera can be set up independently. Then, it's just a matter of combining the streams:

```
AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer(dataOutputs: [videoDataOutput, depthDataOutput, metadataOutput])
```